# is it possible to use a visual studio 2010 c++ code on a linux machine?

Tags: linux, visual-studio

Newbie here. I made a project in visual studio 2010, and it works perfectly. Now i need to compile and run this code in a machine that runs ubuntu. Is there some export/import method, or how does it work (of course assuming such thing is possible).

What i am thinking is making a makefile in visual studio, then take the code and compile it in ubuntu? does such thing make sense?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean take Visual Studio source code and compile it on Linux:  the answer is yes, though there may be anywhere from *zero* to *a lot of* work to make the code compile properly and run.  It all depends on programming choices.  Unfortunately, standard practice with Visual Studio generally is to use the most Microsoft-specific API features, thus greatly complicating porting to a POSIX or Linux environment.  It is possible to make most non-GUI choices very portable, however a GUI intensive program is the least portable unless a cross-platform GUI API is used.

If you mean take the resulting `.exe` file output from Visual Studio and run that on Linux, that is usually *much* easier.  Install the [Wine package](http://www.winehq.org/), (`yum install wine` or whatever the Ubuntu equivalent is) and fire up the program with `wine program.exe`.  I have had very good luck (98+%) running Windows programs this way.  The major exceptions are Microsoft software:  in particular Visual Studio uses many non-standard Windows API operations, so much so that the Wine developers call VS's support level ["garbage"](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892), a surprising outlier considering the number of Windows games which are well behaved and run under Wine straight out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

In an ideal world, the code is independent of any IDE or build chain, which keeps its own metadata saparate. Windows doesn't play nice with Linux.

On the other hand if you set up your project with CMake or something like that, then you can generate Visual Studio projects for a given code base just as easily as Linux makefiles.

You shouldn't need to change much code itself. Or, at least you should be aware of what is windows-specific. You probably will have to expend some effort in creating your CMakeList.txt or whatever you end up using, but it's pretty easy once you're familiar with it.